# How to define a matrix to have the lowest memory consumption?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix, numpy-ndarray

I have 10000000 integers that I want to add in a matrix of 10000000 * 256 dimensions.I have defined three types of matrices to compare which definition has the lowest memory consumption I have shown below:

```
1) np.zeros ([row, col], dtype = int)
2) np.empty ([row, col], dtype = int)
3) csr_matrix ((row, col), dtype = np.int) .toarray ()
```

Among these definitions, the matrix defined as Spars has the least amount of memory. The first two definitions each have 2 GB of memory usage but the last matrix consumes 1 GB of memory. Are there other methods or libraries that compress the matrix as much as possible and consume less memory?

Comment: A numpy array with shape (row, col) and type `int` uses the same memory, regardless of how you construct it.  You can look at the `nbytes` or calculate `row*col*8`  (with 8 bytes for dtype int).  A sparse matrix without any nonzero values is quite small, but that doesn't save any memory when converted to dense: `toarray()`.

Comment: The memory of an array is fixed by shape and dtype.  Values, whether 0 or 255 or something else doesn't change that.

Comment: If your values are between 0 and 255 you should make the dtype np.uint8. This will require only 1 byte if storage per array entry.